# Can I run a method on the main thread from a separate thread?

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, multithreading

I'm reading data from a serial port, but the DataReceived event of SerialPort is handled on it's own thread. I want to handle this on the main thread, but simply declaring an event and raising it still results in it being processed on the SerialPort thread. I'm assuming I need to declare a delegate I can call, but I don't see how that would work.

For example, I want to call Sub HandleDataReceived() on the main thread from the DataReceived thread, having HandleDataReceived() run on the main thread. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the main thread is a UI thread, you can use its [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or call [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx).

Comment: Thank you; I'll look more into Control.BeginInvoke as it looks better suited for my needs.

Comment: Yep, I was waiting to see if I could get it to work. Thanks again!